# How to install inltk in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

While installing `nltk` I am facing this problem.

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

And here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64nxE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should either use a `!` in front of your bash installation instructions like this

```sh
!pip install torch==1.4.0+cpu torchvision==0.5.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Or do it in a terminal window by clicking on *File>New>Terminal* and install the packages from there. To restart your kernel, click on *Kernel>Restart*. In general I would advise you to read an [introduction to Jupyter notebooks to start](https://realpython.com/jupyter-notebook-introduction/).

Answer (score 0):

`!pip3 install nltk` will do the job. The `!` at the start, tells the notebook to run the succeeding statement as a shell command. You will see an output like this

```
Collecting nltk
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f6/1d/d925cfb4f324ede997f6d47bea4d9babba51b49e87a767c170b77005889d/nltk-3.4.5.zip (1.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.5MB 873kB/s ta 0:00:01
Collecting six (from nltk)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/eb/1f97cb97bfc2390a276969c6fae16075da282f5058082d4cb10c6c5c1dba/six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: nltk
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for nltk ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/swati/.cache/pip/wheels/96/86/f6/68ab24c23f207c0077381a5e3904b2815136b879538a24b483
Successfully built nltk
Installing collected packages: six, nltk
Successfully installed nltk-3.4.5 six-1.14.0
```